# Как можно оптимизировать графику на OpenGl?

Tags: разработка-игр, opengl, графика

Решил написать майнкрафт на ассемблере с OpenGL, но возникают проблемы с частотой кадров даже при не очень большом количестве блоков. Использовал и frustum scaling и шейдера вроде оптимизировал, однако fps всё-равно вообще не радует. Слышал, что нужно оптимизировать количество вызовов на отрисовку к видеокарте, потому что пока у меня вызывается отдельная отрисовка на каждый блок, однако не знаю сильно ли это помогает. Вопрос в том какие методы оптимизации существуют (не влазя в дебри), ведь я понимаю, что мне уже не хватает каких-то концептуальных знаний и понимания того, что и на сколько влияет.
Если я ксати угадал с тем, что мне нужно оптимизировать количество вызовов на отрисовку к видеокарте, то буду очень признателен, если приложите пример реализации этого на OpenGL.

Comment: *"вызывается отдельная отрисовка на каждый блок"* - Это конечно трешь. *"не хватает каких-то концептуальных знаний и понимания того, что и на сколько влияет"* - откройте профилировщик. Для простого майнкрафто-подобного рендеринга будет достаточно одного прохода для отрисовки всех блоков.